# How to replace single element of array

Tags: java, arrays

I will have a series of random arrays similar to.

```
array1[] = {1,2,3,0,0,5,6}
array1[] = {1,2,0,0,4,5,6}
```

I want them to end up like, so I **replace the first 0 with X.**

```
array1[] = {1,2,3,X,0,5,6}
array1[] = {1,2,X,0,4,5,6}
```

the code I'm using replaces all zeroes giving instead of just one.

```
array1[] = {1,2,3,X,X,5,6}
array1[] = {1,2,X,X,4,5,6}
```

Which isn't what I'm looking for. I'd be happy just replacing either one but only one.
The code I'm using,

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(fruit[i] == 0)
            fruit[i]=X;
    }
```

Hope that was clear, thanks for any help! Being stuck at this for a little while now.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: I've also tried to sort the array so the first element is 0 and then it's easy to replace but that doesn't work when X is a negative number, which it will be sometimes in this case.

Comment: I see no need to downvote this question. Despite it's simple answer Dodo has clearly put some work in here to describe it properly. So +1 for good formulated quertion.

Comment: (But don't forget to accept the ansert!) (the green checkmark left to the correct answer's rating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using break.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(fruit[i] == 0) {
        fruit[i] = X;
        break;
    }
}
```

This will ensure only one is changed, max.

Comment: thanks! I tried this earlier but I forgot the curly brackets in the if statement.. feel like an idiot but glad it's sorted. Thanks!

Comment: @Dodo Don't forget to accepot the answer :).